# How do i auto delete a row of data in my database after 15days?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i want the site(if possible the database itself) to delete a row data in the database, without interacting with the site like opening or loading it.

i searched some tutorials/post but i only saw codes that need to be interacted.

Thanks.

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Which database environment are you using? MySQL on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have access to cronjob you could run a small script at the bottom of a website. With the script, you check when the script was last run and if it's 15 days ago, check the dates of the rows in the database.

But, cronjob is easier, better and preferred.

Comment: Better run it every day, otherwise you might end up with rows that are 29 days old.

Answer (score 8):

Run a cronjob or other scheduled process on your server

Answer (score 2):

You need to record the date that the entry was made in the db. Then write a script that would run as a cron job to check the dates of rows in the table and delete if it is up to 15 days